# Get the latest full week's data for analysis in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given sales data, where I have items and sales on a particular date. Now, the company wants to analyze the latest full week’s data against the total sales of company.

```
Item    date           Sales
Apple   08/25/2020       10
Orange 08/24/2020        20
Orange 08/21/2020        30
```

Now the full week is defined by a complete week from Sunday-Saturday. In the above made up example, it is clear that, these two data **Apple    08/25/2020  10 Orange 08/24/2020        20** are from days Friday and Thursday respectively, so it is not a full week, hence we cannot take this week’s data. We need to check the last week’s data which would be for **08/21/2020**
I was given 10 minutes to think on this, my immediate solution was, find the weekday number for the maximum data in the table. And subtract it from 7. If that is equal to 0 then we have a full week, and we can take the max date as the end date of our analysis and use a dateadd() to subtract 7 days from the max date to make it a start date. If I have something other than the 0, for example 6, then I use dateadd to go 6 days prior to my max date and use it as end date, again go 7 days behind this and get the start date.

```
CREATE TABLE SALES(Item nvarchar(10), dates date, Sales Numeric)

INSERT INTO SALES VALUES('Apple',CAST('08/25/2020' AS DATE),10),
('Orange',CAST('08/24/2020' AS DATE),20),
('Orange',CAST('08/21/2020' AS DATE),30)


WITH end_dates AS
(
SELECT CASE WHEN 7-DATEPART(dw, max(dates))=0 THEN max(dates)
ELSE DATEADD(day,- DATEPART(dw, max(dates)),max(dates)) END AS end_date
FROM SALES
),
Full_Week_Date AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(day,-6,end_date) as start_date ,end_date FROM end_dates
)
SELECT (SELECT SUM(SALES.sales)*100 FROM SALES JOIN Full_Week_Date ON(dates BETWEEN start_date AND end_date))/(SELECT SUM(SALES.sales) FROM SALES)  AS revenue_per
```

This is the best  I could think of, but the interviewer said, given a large amount of data, this would run like forever. What would be an optimum solution for this problem? I only want to know, how to get start and end date of the week that I want to analyze. Rest the revenue and % revenue will be fairly easy I believe if I have this in place.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (I doubt both will execute that query.)

Comment: I am using SQL Server. And for getting the start and end date only it should work. I will really appreciate if you can let me know, what I am doing wrong? TIA

Comment: @jarlh: The query works in SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an actual database the query to use will depend on indexes and other things. For a basic answer, there are a few things to consider here.

They state "a complete week from Sunday-Saturday". Unless you are reporting at 11:59PM on Saturday you never will really have that full weeks sales in the same week. Since that is the case there is no reason to do all the checks you mentioned. They will cause unnecessary processing.

One thing you didn't mention is if the total company sales included the week your sales you are checking are for. I am going to assume they want to exclude that weeks sales.

I am not going to claim this is the most efficient way, but I would do it like this.

```
INSERT INTO #Sales 
VALUES 
    ('Apple', '08/25/2020', 10),
    ('Orange', '08/24/2020', 20),
    ('Orange', '08/21/2020', 30),
    ('Apple', '11/14/2020', 25);

-- Get week to check (last week)
DECLARE @curWeek int = DATEPART(WW, DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE()));

-- Get Sales
SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(SalesAmt, 0)) AS CompanySales
    , (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(SalesAmt, 0)) FROM #Sales WHERE DATEPART(WW, SalesDate) = @curWeek) AS WeekSales
FROM #Sales
WHERE DATEPART(WW, SalesDate) <= @curWeek;
```

Comment: Any entry in the table means it is end of the day entry. And for checking it against total sales, we need to include the current week.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the week you are reporting through. The way the statement is worded, you must contain the full weeks sales from Sunday through Saturday or you have to use the previous week. I would keep it this way. You can't really ever report on current week's sales since end of the week includes Saturday. Therefore you won't have Saturday's full sales until Sunday unless they cut off sales at 5PM or something like that. In which case you you can add more logic to the line declaring the @curWeek.